# How to click span based on text given

Tags: python, selenium

Consider this:
https://www.lanebryant.com/lace-trim-overpiece/prd-358988#color/0000006400

Click What's my size and then click get started. You'll see a drop down that has age ranges. I need to click those based on value that I have already. Consider my code:

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/form/tfc-accordion-group/div[2]/div/div[2]/span/div[2]/div//span[text()=" + " "+ df_temp.age + " " + "]"))).click()
```

df_temp['age'] has value 16-18

But it doesn't click and gives timeout exception.

Comment: Just print the xpath and paste on web console of developer tools to check whether it's correct or not.

Comment: last component where the text is available is `label` not `span`

Comment: @Kaushik explain

Comment: this is xpath i got `//*[@id="productDetail"]/section/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/ul/li[3]/label`

Comment: @Yun I typed it in console on chrome. It turned red. How do I know if its correct or not

Comment: @Kaushik I right clicked and inspect it. It redirects to span

Comment: try with the one i pinged

Comment: @Kaushik doesnt work

Comment: @FatimaArshad Sorry, I didn't make it clear. Click the 'Elements' tab (in depveloper tool), using crtl+F and paste the xpath. If element can be found, that is correct.

Comment: @Yun copy pasted this xpath /html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/form/tfc-accordion-group/div[2]/div/div[2]/span/div[2]/div//span[text()= "16-18" ], doesnt find element

Comment: how do I correct it

Answer (score 0):

First click to the dropdown to open list of options, than click on item using `//div[@value="ageRange.id" and contains(.,"16 - 18")]` or `//div[@value="ageRange.id" and normalize-space(.)="16 - 18"]` xpath:

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[aria-label="Age"]'))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@value="ageRange.id" and contains(.,"16 - 18")]'))).click()
```

Comment: wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@value="ageRange.id" and normalize-space(.)=' + df_temp.age+')]'))).click()   still doesnt work

Comment: Because you `df_temp['age']` has value `16-18`instead of `16 - 18`, there are spaces before and after `-`

Comment: Doesnt click it and gives timeout except

Comment: Use `visibility_of_element_located` instead of `element_to_be_clickable `. Check the answer update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202331/discussion-between-sers-and-fatima-arshad).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you, for the detail of every step see the code comments.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Configure the webdriver and webdriver-wait instances
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)


# Load the webpage
driver.get("https://www.lanebryant.com/lace-trim-overpiece/prd-358988#color/0000006400")
time.sleep(5)

# Open the popup
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="358988"]//td/a[@class="tfc-popup-click-open"]'))).click()
time.sleep(4)

# Find the popup iframe and make driver to focus the same
popup_iframe = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@aria-label, "True Fit")]/iframe')))
driver.switch_to.frame(popup_iframe) 
# To switch the focus back to the main content window,
# execute: driver.switch_to.default_content()

# Click the get-started button
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@class, "tfc-cfg-nav-button")]/button'))).click()

# Find the age dropdown
age_dropdown = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, '//*[@class="tfc-select-custom"]/button')))

# Let's say you want to select age group: 
# 35-44, so minAge here is 35
min_age = 35

# Activate the age dropdown and select and click the desired option
age_dropdown.click()
age_option = wait.until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, '//*[@class="tfc-select-custom"]//div[@class="tfc-select-body"]/div/span[contains(text(),%s)]' % (min_age))))
age_option.click()

time.sleep(20)
```